# Java null objects form array

Tags: java, arrays, object

so, i have a program and i need to get an object of an array. So i have to check every object there, but it shows an error. I think it is because the get of an null object is not working. How should i do it? I am new with this...

the get is a simple return this.x, but i think it is breaking because of the null

```
public Sunflower get(int x, int y) {

boolean found=false;
Sunflower sun = null;

for(int i=0; i<MAX && found==false; i++) {

    if(array[i].getX() == x && array[i].getY() == y) sun= array[i];
}
    return sun;
}
```

Thank you for your help
---------------------------EDIT

Adding the array[i]!=null is not working. Same error. I think just looking the position where nothing exist is givinf the problem maybe. i Changed the Max for the size of the array, more logic. i need to check in the position, lets say (7,8), so i look the x and y objects, but i think if it doesnt find anything its giving the error.
somothing like this.:

```
public void update(){

Sunflower sun = game.getSFinPosition(x, y-1);
if(sun!=null&& sun.getVida()!=0) sun.setLife();
```

}

i get the asignation doesnt work if it diesnt find anything, but i tried writing it inside the if and nothing... so no idea.

Comment: Let's see the error. Also, we don't know how the `array` is created.

Comment: can you post the error log too ...which might be more informative for folks here

Comment: Does MAX is greater than array.length ?

Comment: Consider indenting your code more readably if you would like people to read it.

Comment: Just add the error itself to the question. It will help **a lot**.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for null element before trying to access member variable.
Also you can use break instead of using a boolean found.

public Sunflower get(int x, int y) {

```
Sunflower sun = null;
for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++) {

    if(array[i] && array[i].getX() == x && array[i].getY() == y) {
        sun= array[i];
        break;
    }
}
return sun;
```

}

Comment: oh i see, so just skip the null. That might work. Thank you dude, i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **array.length** to get the maximum index of the array, if you want to check all elements. Also you can check if the element is null and skip it:

```
public Sunflower get( int x, int y ) {
    boolean found = false;
    Sunflower sun = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length && found == false; i++) {
        if (array[i] != null &&
                array[i].getX() == x && array[i].getY() == y) {
            sun = array[i];
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return sun;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working sample given your code, with some improvements:

```
public class Main {
  public static class Sunflower {
    private int x, y;

    Sunflower(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    int getX() {
      return x;
    }

    int getY() {
      return y;
    }
  }

  public static class Getter {
    private Sunflower[] array = {new Sunflower(1, 0), new Sunflower(0, 1), null, new Sunflower(3, 1)};

    Sunflower get(int x, int y) {
      for (Sunflower s : array) {
        if (s == null) continue;
        if (s.getX() == x && s.getY() == y) return s;
      }

      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Getter getter = new Getter();

    assert getter.get(1, 0) != null;
    assert getter.get(1, 0) != null;
    assert getter.get(3, 1) != null;
    assert getter.get(3, 2) == null;
  }
}
```

The function you're most interested in:

```
Sunflower get(int x, int y) {
  for (Sunflower s : array) {
    if (s == null) continue;
    if (s.getX() == x && s.getY() == y) return s;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Changes:

1. For loop with a foreach
2. Check whether the value is null
3. Return without setting the `found` variable
4. Return null otherwise